# Is devotion towards Gods and studying of scriptures sufficient to get Moksha ? Or Guru essential for getting Moksha?

Tags: guru

Krishna in Gita has said that to know dharma one should follow scriptures .(Gita 16.23)
Plus one should always be devoted towards him and always remember him .
He has never said about role of guru.
I want to know if Guru is essential in spiritual journey ?

Comment: "This Atman is not to be attained by the study of the vedas, nor by the highest intellect, nor by much learning. Whom the Atman seeks, he gets the Atman; unto him He discloses His glory." Mundaka Upanishad III.ii.3 The Atman seeks he who longs for Him.

Answer (score 3):

Lord Krishna, does talk about Guru , in Gita 4.34.

> *tad viddhi pranipatena pariprashnena sevaya.......*
> Learn the Truth by approaching a spiritual master. Inquire from him with reverence and render service unto him. Such an enlightened Saint can impart knowledge unto you because he has seen the Truth
> (Swami Mukundananda , Gita 4.34)

(*PS:
In Vedic age , Guruparampara was the backbone of spiritual tradition, where a Preceptor(Who had immense moral conduct)  was held in reverence.. Vidya(Education) was considered sacrosanct,  which inculcated dharma , thus, a pathway for moksha..In modern times , Education is  made commercial. A teacher isn't revered (mostly as in west),also the purpose of this education is for a student to aquire artha(worldly wealth) (thru a laukika Vidya)to satisfy his/her kama.With the current mindset , it may not be possible to bridge the gap , and truly understand the greatness of a Guru. (why at all a Guru is required))*

A seeker of *knowledge* , has a quest for Adyatma Vidya , (which is beyond precincts of any laukika Vidya)..Here the Guru is Wise (one has realised the self..ie.. who has truly tasted the sweetness of honey ,  not the one who had heard it from scriptures).'Wise' Guru is capable of teaching the truth and guide a true seeker of knowledge .

> The letter ‘gu’ stands for darkness, the letter ‘ru’ stands for its removal.
> The Guru is so called because Guru removes the darkness (of ignorance).
>  Guru Gita
> Skanda Purana.

Vivekachudamani , verses 32,37 is in conformity with Gita 4.34

*A Guru a confer emancipation from samsara to an eligible seeker*

> The inquirer about the truth of the Ātman who is possessed of the above-mentioned means of attainment should approach a wise preceptor, who confers emancipation from bondage.
> (VC 32)

> There are good souls, calm and magnanimous, who do good to others as does the spring, and who, having themselves crossed this dreadful ocean of birth and death, help others also to cross the same, without any motive whatsoever.(VC 37)

In Uddhava Gita Lord Krishna tells how Avadutta Dattatreya discovered 24 Gurus(animate and inanimate) by observing the world. Though highly improbable it isn't impossible to find such a spiritual luminaries who hadnt approached a particular Guru.